# Docker-compose down

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, containers, devops

I ran the following command docker-compose down to stop the running docker containers, but besides that I saw that it removes the volumes. I had a volume of a database. Then I lost my volume. Can someone tell me how I can recover this database data?

I haven't tried anything yet

Comment: When you rip it down, the volumes are trashed. You can always just stop/suspend which preserves the volumes. If the volumes are gone not sure there's a way to recover it, short of sending your drive to a data recovery expert.

Comment: `docker-compose down` should not delete volumes unless you add the `-v` command line option. If the volume has been deleted then it's gone; the files have been deleted from the filesystem and unless you were making backups the data is not recoverable.

Comment: Unless you have launched `docker-compose down -v`  or `docker volume rm volume_name` - your docker volumes are safe. It is just that your docker volume is detached and new docker volume is created which got attached to your new containers.

Comment: Please verify existing docker volumes using `docker volume ls`.

Comment: yes, existing volumes